# mysql query logic for fetching data from 3 related tables on certain condition

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a programming contest controller on web platform, which has some tables, including 'contest', 'problem' and 'relation' tables, which I'm having the trouble with.

structure of 'contest' table: contest_id, contest_name (for simplicity)

```css
============================
|contest_id | contest_name |
|-----------|--------------|
|          1|  Test Contest|
|-----------|--------------|
|          2|   Another One|
============================
```

structure of 'problem' table: problem_id, problem_name (for simplicity)

```css
============================
|problem_id | problem_name |
|-----------|--------------|
|          1|     A Problem|
|-----------|--------------|
|          2| Other Problem|
============================
```

structure of 'relation' table: rel_id, contest_id, problem_id

```css
===========================================
|   rel_id  | contest_id   |  problem_id  |
|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|          1|             1|             1|
|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|          2|             1|             2|
|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|          3|             1|             8|
|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|          4|             2|             5|
|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|          5|             2|             8|
===========================================
```

I'm planning to allow the admin to set up the system once then have as many contests as s/he wants, so the same 'problem_id' can be assigned to multiple 'contest_id'.

For a single contest, I'm fetching all the 'problem_id's for that contest with all the content of that problem with this query:

```css
SELECT * FROM `problem` JOIN `relation` on `relation`.`problem_id` = `problem`.`problem_id` WHERE `contest_id` = 3 // say the id is 3
```

But when editing the contest and adding some more problems in it, I need to fetch ONLY those problems to show which are NOT ALREADY in the same contest.

I tried this but didn't work, gave me some duplicates and other contest problems:

```css
SELECT * FROM `problem` LEFT JOIN `relation` on `relation`.`problem_id` != `problem`.`problem_id` WHERE `contest_id` != 3
```

I can do the same thing inside php, using two loops, one for iterating through all the 'problem_id's in the whole system and inside that loop, another loop for iterating through all the 'problem_id's of that contest only, or vice versa. But it'll cost me an O(n^2) complexity which I'm sure can be avoided using mysql query. Any idea to do it in php more efficiently will be also good for me. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MYSQL `NOT IN()` to remove the problems that are already in the `relation` table for the selected `contest`.

```
SELECT * FROM problem WHERE 
    problem.problem_id NOT IN (SELECT problem_id FROM relation WHERE contest_id = 2)
```

`NOT IN()` makes sure that the expression proceeded does not have any of the values present in the arguments.